# Sum of an array

Tags: c, function, loops

I can't understand why my program only prints the first number in the array.
it seems it loops only once and then something breaks the loop. The output is 232.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[]){
 int sum_arr(int arr[]);
 int arr[5]={232,44,3,4,5};
 printf("%d\n",sum_arr(arr));

 return 0;
}

sum_arr(int arr[]){ 
  int i,sum=0,sizeofarr=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
  for(i=0;i<=(sizeofarr-1);i++){
    sum+=arr[i];
  }
  return (sum);
}
```

Comment: The implicit `int` isn't supported since C99. Don't use it any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

nt main( int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    int sum_arr( int arr[], size_t n );
    int arr[5] = { 232, 44, 3, 4, 5 };

    printf( "%d\n", sum_arr( arr, sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr ) ) );

    return 0;
}


  int sum_arr( int arr[], size_t n )
  { 
      int i = 0, sum = 0;

      for ( ; i < n ;i++ )
      {
          sum += arr[i];
      }

      return ( sum );
  }
```

The problem with your code is that an arrray passed as an argument is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. So inside function sum_array you used sizeof( int * ) / sizeof( int ) that for your system is equal to 1.

Take into account this quote from the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type **‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object** and is not an lvalue. If the array object
>   has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: The problem with your code is ... that an array argument is not actually an array argument, but a disguised pointer argument.

Comment: @Deduplicator You are totally wrong. arr is defined as an array. Simply it is converted to a pointer.

Comment: I think you stumbled over linguistic difficulties there. Or you read the standard wrong.

Comment: @Deduplicator There is no linguistic problem. There is a definition of arr as an array in the program. arr is not defined as a pointer.

Comment: A function argument declared with array notation is not an array, but a disguised pointer. There is no decaying involved. I know there is exactly one definition of `arr` as an array in the program, in `main()`. That's not important for the function argument type though.

Comment: @Deduplicator I see that it is you who has linguistic difficulties. arr is not a function parameter.  It is defined as an array in function main.

Comment: @Deduplicator You have only one definition of arr. You have no other definitions of arr. So arr is an array and neither something else. In expressions it is converted to rvalue of a pointer to its first element. I think it would be correctly.

Comment: Seems we are not really communicating (and the error is at least partially on my side). Let me try it again: Yes, we have a definition of `arr` as a local variable of array-type in `main`. That one is not important in `sum_arr` though, which (in OPs code) had exactly one argument, of pointer-type (which is the `arr` I talked about).

Comment: @Deduplicator There is a postfix expression of a function call where arr is used. In function there is a parameter that is a local variable that was assigned by the argument expression. This assignment does not use an array. It uses an expression of pointer type that was got due to the implicit conversion of arr to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: a couple of things.  1) This code snipit: sizeof( *arr ) should be sizeof( int ).  2) this line: int sum_arr( int arr[], size_t n ); is a prototype, it should be before the main() function declaration, not buried within the body of main().  When within the body of main() that prototype is only seen in main() and not where the function is actually declared, so the default (all int parameters and return) is used.

Comment: @user3629249 Your comment is wrong. sizeof( *arr ) and sizeof( int ) are equivalent.  There is no need to declare the function outside main because it is used only in main.

Answer (score 4):

```
sizeofarr = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
```

This trick to calculate the size of an array doesn't work. Because in the function, `arr` decays to a pointer, not an array.

To fix the problem, pass the size explicitly.

Comment: It does not decay to a pointer, the function-argument **is** a pointer, even though it looks like it isn't.

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm referring to the array `arr` in `main()` vs the pointer `arr` in `sum_arr()`.

Comment: Still does not decay in the function, but when passed, which is earlier. Otherwise you could somehow prevent the decay when in the function.

Answer (score 2):

Remember, in C when pass an array *as an argument* to a function, actually you're passing a **pointer** to an array.

Since the size of a pointer and an `int` is 4 or 8, you'll be getting `sizeof(int *)/sizeof int` (**4/4=1** for 32-bit machines and **8/4=2** for 64-bit ones) which is **1** or **2**.

Comment: The size of an `int` is 16 bits or more, which is at least one byte. THe size of a pointer is at least one byte. On modern systems, they are normally 4 respective 4/8 bytes each.

Answer (score 0):

In conclusion, array names in a C program are (in most cases) converted to pointers.One exception is when we use the sizeof operator on an array. If arr was converted to a pointer in this contest, sizeof(arr) would give the size of a pointer and not of the actual array, which would be rather useless, so in that case a means the array itself.

In my program the array passed in the function is converted to a pointer. Then, sizeof(arr) in the sum_arr function gives the size of a pointer and not of the actual array.

This program should be execute in this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZEOFARR(arr) (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))

int main(){

 int sum_arr(int arr[],int size);
 int arr[5]={232,44,3,4,5};
 printf("The sum of the array is: %d\n",sum_arr(arr,SIZEOFARR(arr)));


  return 0;
}

int sum_arr(int arr[],int size){
  int i,sum=0;
  for(i=0;i<size;i++){
  sum+=arr[i];
  }
  return (sum);
}
```

Comment: In fact you rewrote my answer by your own words.:)

Comment: In fact, yes. I did, because @Deduplicator didn't agree with you. I made a little research about the subject.